# How to access sibling properties from an array in a knockout model iteration

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model in which I iterate rows and columns to dynamically generate an HTML table. The first row of the `rows[]` array will be a simple string array containing the column headers; proceeding rows will contain an object that holds the column data, as well as metadata about that row (i.e. the `sobjectid` of the row).

How can I access the sobjectid in the html/view? I've played around with Knockout's `$data` and `$parent` [binding context variables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) in the `foreach: rows` iteration and `foreach: columns` iteration with no success.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EQnr/)

```
var viewModel = {
    id: 'Account1',
    heading: 'Account',
    rows: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// Ajax data populates viewModel structure...

// Header row
viewModel.rows.push(['Name', 'Title', 'Position']);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    viewModel.rows.push({
        sobjectId: i,
        sobjectType: 'Account',
        columns: ['Matt' + i, 'Sr.', 'Software Engineer']
    });   
}

<table data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: $index() === 0 -->
    <tbody>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
            <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

Comment: Where do you want to display the subjectid in view?

Comment: @nemesv in my current case, anywhere is fine. Once I know how to access it, I can take it from there. To answer the posed question, putting it in within the <tr data-bind...foreach columns> would be suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `foreach: columns` you can just access your property with `$parent.sobjectId`

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98v2a/).

Or if you move your `foreach` inside the `tr` and use the comment syntax then you can just write `data-bind="text: sobjectId"`:

```
<tr>
    <th>Subject Id</th>
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
        <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
```

And

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: sobjectId"></td>
    <!-- ko foreach: columns -->
       <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zYYB/).